# Converting a user's phone number into english numbers

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an application that user must insert his number and send it to the server.
The problem that i am encountering is that some users insert their numbers in their native language(For example Urdu, arabic, Indian or others)
What I want is to convert all numeric numbers from different languages to English numbers(1,2,3...) and then send it to server.
Is there a possible way to achieve that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please note that this has nothing to do with the `xcode` IDE so I have removed that tag. Please could you also share code of that you have tried?

Comment: So the input would for example be "one hundred and twenty three" (english) or "einhunderdreiundzwanzig" (german) ?

Comment: No, what i meant that if user entered @"٠١‎٢‎٣" the real number that should be sent to server will be @"0123"

Comment: Just as a reminder: You have to check the input on the server side as well. So always assume that data sent to your server may be corrupt. Also: Why do you send the number as a string? If you convert it to an actual number format, you can save some bytes (and avoid the character formatting problem).

Comment: Wait... are you using this for phone numbers? i.e. is the number the user enters their phone number? If so it would have been awesome to mention this because phone numbers are very different from actual numbers.

Comment: oh sorry not mentioning that. Yes it is for phone numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be surprised if you can't just do...

```
NSInteger blah = [enteredString intValue];
// you will have to know if it's an int, float, double, etc...
// the entered number is still a number just using a different font (I guess).
// the shape of the number 2 comes entirely from the font so I don't see why this wouldn't work
```

But if that doesn't work take a look at the `NSNumberFormatter` class. You should be able to do something like...

```
NSNumberFormatter *nf = [NSNumberFormatter new];
NSNumber *number = [nf numberFromString:enteredString];
```

Either way should work. Try the first one first. If that doesn't work then give the number formatter a go. You **may** have to set the locale of the number formatter.

**Tested with a working project**

```
// This is the only code.
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self getNumber];
    return YES;
}

- (void)getNumber
{
    NSInteger number = [self.textField.text intValue];

    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)number);
}

@end
```

I changed the simulator language to Arabic and it worked perfectly.

Screenshot...
[image]

Code...
[image]

**Literal string vs. entered string**

I'm guessing this is because your development language is English.

Anyway, when you enter the literal string `١‎٢‎٣` into Xcode and store it in a string it is different from taking the string `١‎٢‎٣` from an Arabic textfield...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, NSString* arabicNumb =@"٠١‎٢‎٣٤‎٥‎٦‎٧٨";
    NSInteger intValue = [arabicNumb intValue];
    NSLog(@"integer %d ",intValue); //this returned 1
    
    NSNumberFormatter *nf = [NSNumberFormatter new];
    NSNumber *number = [nf numberFromString:arabicNumb];
     NSLog(@"formatter  %@ ",number); //this returned null

Comment: @IphoneUser Did you set the locale of the device to the locale of the numbers you were using?

Comment: Yes i did that and still get null response.

Comment: @IphoneUser I just set up a demo project with a textfield. Changed the (simulator) device language to Arabic and entered "123". It worked perfectly with both methods.

Comment: did you enter 123 in arabic? so the text field text  was ١‎٢‎٣?

Comment: @IphoneUser edited answer to show that it does work.

Comment: @IphoneUser I did this with NSNumber and NSNumberFormatter. It also worked perfectly.

Comment: I have tried it by inserting a NSString programmatically as shown above, i will try it now with textfield and get back to you with the result

Comment: @IphoneUser there is a difference between entering the unicode chars `١‎٢‎٣` and entering the numbers `123` (and then the font representing them with the symbols `١‎٢‎٣`). The former is not using numbers. The latter is the difference between using Comic Sans, Times New Roman and Helvetica to display numbers differently. Your literal string is not the same as what is displayed when the device is in Arabic and it is showing `123` as `١‎٢‎٣`.

Comment: I tried it in the textField and that worked perfectly for the limit of integer, when user enter a number larger than 10 digits then this will not work, What should be done in order to receive larger numbers?

Comment: @IphoneUser Use `integerValue` for `NSInteger` that will give you 64 bit numbers if the device supports it. Or use long numbers. However, this is nothing to do with this question. This will happen in English, Arabic, Chinese, etc... it is down to the fact that int is 32 bits. Please accept my answer if it solves your question. Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to convert unicode chars to english numbers if i set it by code(NSString* arabicNumb =@"٠١‎٢‎٣٤‎٥‎٦‎٧٨")? Your answer solved the question that i asked but not my entire problem. I have a limit of 20 digits.

Comment: Sorry, i thought it is the same to convert numbers and phone numbers, my mistake. So what will be the solution of my issue?

Comment: @IphoneUser The best I can do is. `NSNumberFormatter *nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    
    NSNumber *number = [nf numberFromString:self.textField.text];

    nf.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en"];
    
    NSString *string = [nf stringFromNumber:number];` but this will drop the lead 0.

Comment: great man.. thank you so much and i apologize for my mistake of clarifying the issue.

Comment: No worries, make sure you ask the question that you really want to ask in the future. Sometimes people ask the question that they think they need to ask but then all meaning gets lost because they are not asking the right question.